# Adding RelativeLayout Child to a Parent Layout Dynamically does not work

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I'm trying to inflate Child Views to a Parent view dynamically but it throws an error.

**I'm trying to add each RelativeLayout child below one another**

Here's my code:

**Parent Layout**

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/work_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Child Layout**

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#ffffff">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/work_pic"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:src="@mipmap/image_placeholder"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Inflation code:**

```
RelativeLayout parent = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.work_list);

//array containing all children ids
ArrayList<Integer> children = new ArrayList<>();

//adding 10 children to the parent
for(int i=0;i<10;i++) {

    RelativeLayout child = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.work_list); //new child
    child.setId(i); //setting an id for the child
    children.add(i); //adding the child's id to the list

    if(i!=0) //if it isn't the 1st child, stack them below one another, since the 1st child does not have a child to stack below
    {
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params 
                           = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                params.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, children.get(i - 1)); //stack it below the previous child
                child.setLayoutParams(params);
    }

    parent.addView(child); //add the new child
}
```

The error I get:

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child
>   already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent
>   first. at
>   com.hellotest.TestingDynamics.onCreate(TestingDynamics.java:43)

Line 43 points to this line:

```
parent.addView(child);
```

What am I doing wrong? If I'm wrong, what's the correction to my code, guys?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`RelativeLayout child = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.work_list); //new child`

This is not true. `findViewById` returns *existing* child, which is already in the layout. You have to create new `RelativeLayout` by using its constructor:

`RelativeLayout child = new RelativeLayout(this);`

Comment: That got rid of the error but I don't see the Child Layouts in the view now. Looks like they dont get inflated :/

Comment: Oh Of course nothing appears, I havent set the layout to be inflated :D How do I do that mate?

Comment: @Earthling you have accepted the answer - do you still need help? Inflation is an alternative to creating a layout with constructor, so you don't need to inflate layout if you're creating it programmatically. I'd say you don't (haven't) see them because they're empty, and their size is set to `WRAP_CONTENT`